# Stream as constructor arg sometimes fully evaluated during early class initialization

Tags: scala, stream, initialization, lazy-evaluation

Streams can be used as class constructor arguments:

```
scala> ( 0 to 10).toStream.map(i =>{println("bla" + i); -i})
bla0
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> class B(val a:Seq[Int]){println(a.tail.head)}
defined class B

scala> new B(res0)
bla1
-1
res1: B = B@fdb84e
```

So, the Stream does not get fully evaluated although handed in as a Seq argument, and although being partly evaluated. Works as expected.

I have a class like this:

```
class HazelSimpleResultSet[T] (col: Seq[T], comparator:Comparator[T]) extends HGRandomAccessResult[T] with CountMe
{
  val foo: Int = -1  // col of type Stream[T] already fully evaluated here.

  def count = col.size
  ....
}
```

where HGRandomAccessResult and CountMe are simple interfaces.

I most cases I want to use Streams as col constructor arguments, to avoid costly operations. In the debugger I can follow that it works in some cases, since the value displayed for col remains Stream(xy, ?) and "tlVal = null", even after initialization of HazelSimpleResultSet.

Furthermore, for testing, I include println in the blocks that construct the Streams like this:

```
    keyvalues.foldLeft(Stream.empty[KeyType]){ case (a, b) => ({ println("evaluating "+ b); unpack[KeyType](b)}) #:: a}
```

in order to follow in the Console when exactly the Stream is evaluted.

So, in some cases it works, but in some cases the Stream gets full evaluted during the very first moments of initialization of HazelSimpleResultSet. I cannot see no relevant difference in the Stream handed in, i'm just sure they are unevaluted Streams till that moment.
"Stepping into" with the debugger, I can see that it gets evaluted in the line of the class definition itself, before even reaching the class body, i.e. before initialization of any field.

**EDIT**:
I can define the class in a (suboptimal) way such that no field at all is referencing to the Stream, and still I get that behaviour.

The CountMe interface defines a "count" method, which calls col.size which would then evaluate all the Stream. I tried to define count in terms of a lazy val size, but that didn't make a difference.

I'm a bit at a loss why it doesn't work in some cases. Anybody has any hints about hidden caveats of Streams?

EDIT: 
An important note: The Stream object wraps some serious state that it needs to evaluate, i.e. a reference to a NoSQL database (hazelcast). 
Question: what are the caveats here? Is there something in particular I must take care of when my Stream carries stateful references necessary for evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

If you create `Stream` like this:

```
Stream ({println("eval 1"); 1}, {println("eval 2"); 2})
```

then you are actually calling `Stream.apply` which is implemented like this:

```
/** A stream consisting of given elements */
override def apply[A](xs: A*): Stream[A] = xs.toStream
```

which means that what actually happens is:

1. **All elements are evaluated!**
2. A `Seq` containing these elements is created.
3. A `Stream` is created out of this `Seq`

So as you can see, if you create your `Stream` this way, all its elements are evaluated eagerly. This is not how you create lazily-evaluated `Stream`. What you want to do is probably use `#::` and `#:::` operators that evaluate their operands lazily. Look up [the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) for their usage.

Comment: This was just for demonstration. I do my Streams in a valid way such as : keyvalues.foldLeft(Stream.empty[KeyType]){ case (a, b) => (a ++ Stream(unpack[KeyType](b)))}

Comment: Are you sure that `foldLeft` and `++` use lazy evaluation? I would suspect that they don't.

Comment: @ ghik: I changed to:      keyvalues.foldLeft(Stream.empty[KeyType]){ case (a, b) => ({ println("evaluating "+ b); unpack[KeyType](b)}) #:: a}
and still have the same behaviour. Is that correct way of constructing the Stream?

Comment: @ ghik: I understand you are saying, even though it looks like an unevaluated Stream, it may have been evaluated before anyway. In the debugger, how can I distinguish a truly unevaluated Stream from a Stream backed by a strict Seq?